# Spring JPA Data "OR" query

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am using Spring Data JPA and trying to add a query to my repository.  I was trying to just build the query without the @Query annotation like:

```
List<Item> findByTypeAndStateOrStateAndStartDateBetween(Type type, State s, State s2, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

My goal is to build a query like so:

```
select * from item where type = ? and (state = ? or state = ?) and start_date between ? and ?
```

My problem is with the OR clause.  Is there a way to make sure there are brackets?  Otherwise, the logic isn't right.  The examples I found here:
http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/1.0.0.M1/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation

don't have any or clauses with more than 1 column.

Also, is there a way to pass in a List of objects.  For instance, if I wanted to find items with 3 states I would have to create another query, which doesn't scale very well.

Thanks.

EDIT:

I figured out how to pass of list of states using the @Query notation.  You do it like so:

```
@Query("FROM item i WHERE i.type = ?1 AND i.state IN (?2)")
```

Then you can just pass in a list to the method as the second parameter.  Still don't know how to do this without using the @Query notation.

Comment: I think this is why Spring Data allows you to specify the query, it can only go so far in determining what you want from method name alone.  It's fine for simple queries but once you increase the complexity you're better off telling it exactly what you want instead of making it guess.

Comment: Plus the @Query is much easier to read than a lengthy method name.

Comment: Thanks, this is the conclusion I came to as well.  Just use an @Query.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, you are very close. To do this without `@Query` the `In` or `IsIn` keyword can be used(not sure whether these keywords were supported at the time the question was asked):

```
List<Item> findByTypeAndStateInAndStartDateBetween(Type type, Collection<State> states, Date startDate, Date endDate);
```

> In and NotIn also take any subclass of Collection as parameter as well
>   as arrays or varargs. For other syntactical versions of the very same
>   logical operator check [Repository query keywords](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repository-query-keywords).

This will suffice your need of passing any number of states for the OR criteria.

Reference: Table 4. Supported keywords inside method names in [Query creation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.query-creation) docs

Comment: Thanks.  These keywords were not available when I asked this question.

Answer (score 7):

I wanted to do the same thing with getting all data for a particular station, that was between two dates.

```
findByStartdateBetweenOrEnddateBetweenAndStation(start,end,start,end,station)
Gives you ==>
SELECT...WHERE (startdate between start,end) OR ( enddatebetween start,end AND station=station)
```

And:

```
findByStationAndStartdateBetweenOrEnddateBetween(station, start,end,start,end)
Gives you ==>
SELECT...WHERE (station=station AND startdate between start,end) OR enddatebetween start,end
```

Both are wrong as I wanted:

```
 SELECT...WHERE station=station AND (startdate between start,end OR enddatebetween start,end)
```

Use the @Query to be very specific and don't take chances mixing your AND/OR with the method name.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Query("FROM item i WHERE i.type = :type AND i.state IN (:state1, :state2)")
List<Item> findByTypeAndTypeIn(@Param("type") Type type, @Param("state") State s1, @Param("state2") State s2);
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, and thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts. That's especially important when there's already a couple of answers that have been validated by the community. Under what conditions might your approach be preferred? Are you taking advantage of new capabilities?