# how to do AND and multiple OR parameters method in spring data JPA

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am trying to formulate a method name for this query :

```
  @Query("from Employees where department = ?1 and (fullTime = true or contractor = true or subContractor = true)")
```

I thought this method will do the trick, but it does an and on dept and full time

```
  public List<Employees> findByDepartmentAndfullTimeTrueOrContractorTrueOrSubContractorTrue(String dept);
```

This is a related question : [Spring JPA Data "OR" query](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10287971/1083581) but was asked in 2012. Is there a way to achieve this without having to use `@Query` ?

Comment: You have the query already, so why don't you use a meaningful name, easy to read and understand, use-case-related name for the method and annotate it with `@Query`?

Comment: @JBNizet Its a 'dumbed down' question. And I have to deal with many more such requirements. Would like to avoid the '@Query' as far as possible.

Comment: If you mean that the query is even more complex, that's one more reason to choose a meaningful method name and use the Query annotation. You really don't want method names of 200 characters, that change every time you change the name of an attribute. Using Query is a good thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is currently not supported and probably never will be for a very simple reason:

Derived queries are considered a means to define very simple queries. I admit this is blurry but if you get to `findByDepartmentAndfullTimeTrueOrContractorTrueOrSubContractorTrue` it's time to rethink whether that's actually what you want to expose to clients. It's awkward to write, awkward to read and probably actually more than a collection of predicates but conveying a higher-level meaning and thus should be named in amore descriptive way.

The solution - as you already discovered - is to use `@Query` or Querydsl predicates.